# How to check when one variable increases the other also increases in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to check when one variable increases, the other variable has to increase (and produce a flag where it does not follow this trend) within each group.

Specifically, I'm trying to check within group 1, higher class must have higher rate, and same for group 2,3,..,n. When data does not follow this trend, e.g. class 3 rate is lower than class 2 rate in group 1, I want to create another column to flag the issue.

```
data work.tst;
    input group class rate;
    cards;
1 1 0.1
1 2 0.5
1 3 0.45
1 4 0.7
2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 4
2 4 6
;
run;
```

I don't know how to obtain this. Any helps is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the data as a CARDS data step, rather than a picture?  Also, include the code you have tried.  Both of these will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: Also post the result you want for the input you share.  Make sure the input you share actually has the thing you are looking for.    In the picture you posted all variables are increasing so there is nothing to show what types of issues you are trying to detect.

Comment: Thank you for your input! This is my first time posting question. I edited based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the data is SORTED by GROUP and CLASS and you want to test if RATE is increasing or not.

You can use the DIF() function to calculate the change in RATE between observations (actually between the calls to the DIF() function).  Then for increasing you will want the change to be a positive value.

Example:

```
data want;
  set tst ;
  by group class;
  change=dif(rate);
  if first.group then change=.;
  decreasing = . < change < 0 ;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    group    class    rate    change    decreasing

 1       1        1      0.10       .           0
 2       1        2      0.50      0.40         0
 3       1        3      0.45     -0.05         1
 4       1        4      0.70      0.25         0
 5       2        1      1.00       .           0
 6       2        2      2.00      1.00         0
 7       2        3      4.00      2.00         0
 8       2        4      6.00      2.00         0
```

If you want no change to also be flagged then use <= 0 instead.